# Excel - Count How Many Non-"Yes" or Non-"No" Answers

Tags: excel, countif

Is it possible to use the `COUNTIF` function - or any other function - to find all values which **aren't** equal to "yes" or "no" values?

I am able to use `COUNTIF` to locate all "yes" and "no" answers (also also all blank cells), but I want to extract the "dirty" data from some survey results and include it in the "Missing" total.

I have tried to search for all values that are not equal to "yes" or "no" (by way of using the `NOT` function), but this failed to work.

Can this be done?

**UPDATE:**

Please note that I also suspect that `COUNTIFS` could do the trick, but am unsure exactly how to lay the function out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=COUNTIFS may be best (if available) but with =COUNTIF I'd suggest:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTIF(A:A,"Yes")-COUNTIF(A:A,"No")-COUNTIF(A:A,"=""").
```

If you are counting `yes` and `no` anyway then you could use the results from elsewhere in place of parts of the above formula.

Comment: I modified this slightly to suit my personal needs and this worked perfectly - thank you.

Comment: For the part that takes care of counting blanks, you could use `COUNTBLANK(A:A)` instead of `COUNTIF(A:A,"=""")`.

Comment: Yes, initially I did say that but have since updated my question to include any function - my fault as I wasn't clear enough.  However, the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `COUNTIFS` instead since you need multiple criteria.
Try using `"<>yes"` and `"<>no"` for the `criteria` for `COUNTIFS`.

Something like
`=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"<>yes",A1:A5,"<>no")`